# Getting the same results in snowflake using RANDOM([seed])

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, random-seed

From the snowflake [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/random.html) -

> If a statement that calls RANDOM is executed more than once, there is no guarantee that RANDOM will generate the same set of values each time. This is true whether or not you specify a seed.

What's the use of a random seed if it doesn't allow to create reproducible code? **Is there a way around this, so that if I want to use the same query again I'll get the same rows every time, even if the rows are ordered randomly using a seed**?
For example,

```
SELECT ID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group_name ORDER BY RANDOM(123)) AS random_n
FROM my_table
WHERE random_n < 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Repeatable random numbers are really tricky in a parallel database -- and in general, simply not worth the effort.  This is even harder on cross-platform databases.

As the documentation suggests, the purpose of `random(seed)` is to return the *same* value for multiple calls within a row.  This seems like a micro-efficiency, because you should be able to generate the same effect using a CTE or subquery.

The documentation also suggests using `SEQ` functions for certain purposes.  In fact, you can generate your own repeatable pseudo-random number generator using the seq values -- assuming the underlying ordering of the data is constant.  My guess is that Snowflake prefers this method for a repeatable generator.